# What does an integral with a horizontal bar through it mean?

Tags: integration, notation

In the book "Handbook of Mathematical Functions" by Abramowitz and Stegun, I came across this integration symbol in the first few equations defining the exponential integral functions, pictured below. Does this mean anything, or is it a printing error?

[image: picture of integral with bar through it]

Comment: It's the [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value)

Comment: I bet the notation is explained somewhere in the Handbook.

Comment: http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_1046.htm

Comment: The link has been updated: https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~cbm/aands/page_1046.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [digital copy of the text](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Ecbm/aands/) which was linked by the user [Chappers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3793538/what-does-an-integral-with-a-horizontal-bar-through-it-mean#comment7814730_3793538), this notation is the Cauchy principle value.  This use is listed in the rather extensive index of notation at the end of the text—specifically, in the section labeled [Miscellaneous Notation](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Ecbm/aands/page_1046.htm).

The [Cauchy Principal Value](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CauchyPrincipalValue.html) is a way of assigning a value to certain "improper" integrals which would otherwise be undefined.  If $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ has a singularity at $c \in [a,b]$, then the Cauchy Principal value is given by

$$ -\kern-9pt\int_{a}^{b} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
:= \lim_{\varepsilon\searrow 0} \left[ \int_{a}^{c-\varepsilon} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x + \int_{c+\varepsilon}^b f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right].$$

A similar definition applies if $f$ has a singularity at infinity:

$$ -\kern-9pt\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) = \lim_{R\to\infty} \int_{-R}^{R} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x. $$

In this second case, it is easier to see how Cauchy principal value differs from the "usual" method of assigning a value to an improper integral.  In the usual setting, we define
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
:= \lim_{a\to-\infty} \int_{a}^{c} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x + \lim_{b\to\infty} \int_{c}^{b} f(x),\mathrm{d}x, $$
where $c$ is any real number.  Using this standard definition, the sine function cannot be integrated over the entire real line.  However, the Cauchy principle value *does* exist:

$$ -\kern-9pt\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = \lim_{R\to\infty} \int_{-R}^{R} \sin(x) \,\mathrm{d}x = 0, $$
since sine is an odd function.

It is also well worth noting that $-\kern-7.5pt\int$ is not standardized notation for the Cauchy principal value.  Most authors will, instead, use the notation $PV\kern-4pt\int$, or something similar.  Also, the notation $-\kern-7.5pt\int$ is used by other authors to mean something different.  For example, in his [text on PDEs](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-19-r), Evans uses $-\kern-7.5pt\int$ to denote the average integral over a ball, i.e.
$$ -\kern-9pt\int_{B(x,r)} f(y)\,\mathrm{d}y
= \frac{1}{\mu(B(x,r))} \int_{B(x,r)} f(y)\,\mathrm{d}y,$$
where $B(x,r)$ denotes a ball in $n$-dimensional Euclidean space with center $x$ and radius $r$, and $\mu(B(x,r))$ denotes the $n$-dimensional volume (Lebesgue measure) of that ball.